# Add centered text below div without putting it in the same div

Tags: html, css, svg

I have 3 svg circles together connected by lines and I need to put some long text below every circle. The text must be aligned to the center of the circle.

How can I do that?

I cannot put the text in the same div as the circle because then a bounding box of the div expands and lines are not connected to the circles.

Current result:
[image: Current result]

Desirable result:
[image: Expected result]

https://jsfiddle.net/b5truu2y/4/

```css
.inline div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
  <div>
    <svg width="105" height="105">
      <circle cy="52.5" cx="52.5" r="50" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>
    <svg width="400" height="105">
      <line x1="0" y1="52.5" x2="400" y2="52.5" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5"></line>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>
    <svg width="105" height="105">
      <circle cy="52.5" cx="52.5" r="50" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>
    <svg width="400" height="105">
      <line x1="0" y1="52.5" x2="400" y2="52.5" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5"></line>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div>
    <svg width="105" height="105">
      <circle cy="52.5" cx="52.5" r="50" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="inline">
  <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
  <div>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
  <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*updated as per comment*

If you are open to using a CSS solution (instead of SVG) here is a possible approach. You can update the size of the circle and line as you need.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/g33erxwp/4/)

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  font-size: .875em;
}

.box>div {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 5px solid #5A5A5A;
  position: relative;
}

.circle:after,
.circle:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #5A5A5A;
}

.circle:before {
  left: -10000%;
  width: 10000%;
}

.circle:after {
  right: -10000%;
  width: 10000%;
}

.circle--first:before {
  display: none;
}

.circle--last:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>
    <span class="circle circle--first"></span>
    <p>AAAA</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="circle"></span>
    <p>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="circle circle--last"></span>
    <p>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your solution length of the line changes depending on the text length. I need that all lines remain constant length no matter how long the text is.

Comment: @MindaugasVarkalys Good point, I have updated the code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple SVG way to do this.

```css
.inline > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

.inline div div {
  padding: 0 1em;
  font-size: smaller;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline">
    <div>
        <svg width="100%" height="105" viewBox="0 0 400 105">
            <circle cy="52.5" cx="200" r="50" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent"></circle>
            <line x1="250" y1="52.5" x2="1000" y2="52.5" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5"></line>
        </svg>
        <div>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <svg width="100%" height="105" viewBox="0 0 400 105">
            <line x1="-1000" y1="52.5" x2="150" y2="52.5" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5"></line>
            <circle cy="52.5" cx="200" r="50" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent"></circle>
            <line x1="250" y1="52.5" x2="1000" y2="52.5" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5"></line>
        </svg>
        <div>BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <svg width="100%" height="105" viewBox="0 0 400 105">
            <line x1="-1000" y1="52.5" x2="150" y2="52.5" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5"></line>
            <circle cy="52.5" cx="200" r="50" stroke="#5A5A5A" stroke-width="5" fill="transparent"></circle>
        </svg>
        <div>CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your solution the text is not centered. If I make text shorter, it becomes aligned to the left.

Comment: Sorry. Just add `text-align:center` to the divs. Example updated.